# Create a line break in the title of a plotly bar chart in python

Tags: python, plotly

I want to introduce a line break as the title extends beyond the edge of the figure.

I initially tried '/n' but then read that `<br>` offers the solution - however this doesn't work - see below - what am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"Likert":[0,1],"Total":[10,20]})
fig10 = px.bar(df, x = "Likert", y = "Total", title="This is a long title that I need to split over two lines I mean its really long!!!!  <br> this is the second line")

fig10.show()
```

[image: This is the image of the graph I have created]

Comment: I ran it in my environment, and the title is correctly newlined. I am using the latest version (5.3.1).

Comment: updated question to make it MWE.  Works as required, plotly 5.3.1

Comment: Thanks both - I am running 5.3.1 - but have added to image your edited code creates.....

Comment: Does this happen with the latest version? What OS, Python, and development environment are you using? It may be affected by something other than the application. For reference, the line is also broken in the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CgC9PcuNo25fSAja88zpSoK0esEtCsyY?usp=sharing) environment.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I did it with update_layout() but not directly within the figure creation, might just be a quirk of plotly.express.

```
fig10.update_layout(title={'text': 'first_line<br>second_line'})
```